# Is there an API of all enabled APIs in Google console?

Tags: google-api, google-console-developer

I would like to get a list of all the APIs, which are enabled for my project in Google Developer Console. Is there any way?

PS: I know there is a Google Discovery API, which can be used. But I would rather not apply a filter myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [discovery services API](https://developers.google.com/discovery/) returns a list of all available Google APIs and has nothing to do with your project on Google Developer console.

There is not currently an API that will give you access to the enabled APIs within a project on Google Developers console.  You will have to check manually on the website yourself.